# Flipster P goes outside of parent div

Tags: php, html, advanced-custom-fields, jquery-flipster

I am making a flipster slider where people can give reviews about a company. But the text is flowing outside of the div. I tried numerous things but I cant get it to work like I want it. This is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK0x2.jpg

and this is what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPvVx.jpg

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields Repeater field.

Also, the two lines of text (above the picture) does not have any whitespaces, I don't know why.

This is how its built:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCgbr.jpg

can anyone help me with this?

This is some extra SCSS:

```
.flipster {
    //margin-top: 75px;
    ul {
        height: 483px !important;
        margin-top: 5px;
        .flipster__item--current article {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        li {
            &.flipster__item--future {
                .flipster__item__content {
                    //transform: rotate(0) !important;
                }
            }

            &.flipster__item--past {
                .flipster__item__content {
                    //transform: rotate(0) !important;
                }
            }


            article,
            .flipster article {
                padding: 45px;
                width: 460px;
                margin: 10px auto;
                height: 460px;
                background: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

                .quote {
                    text-align: center;
                    p {
                        font-size: 32px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                }
                .quote-persoon {
                    p {
                        font-size: 18px;
                        color: $oranje;
                        text-align: center;
                        padding: 35px 0 5px 0;
                        display: block;
                    }
                    span {
                        font-size: 16px;
                        width: 100%;
                        display: block;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    img {
                        margin: 35px auto 0 auto;
                        display: block;
                        border-radius: 75px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .flipster__button {
        opacity: 1;
        svg {
            color: $oranje;
        }
    }
}
```

When I reload the page, I can see it is all inside the div how it should be but then it just quickly jumps out

Comment: Can you place create a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. it was in the ul.flipster__container. there was a css line: white-space: nowrap; 
no idea why that would be of any use